# How to display admin login?

Tags: users

I have created two logo block in left and right in my page.tpl.php page.
I am not able to see admin login.

Please guide me.

Comment: What do you mean by admin login? Is it different than the normal user login form that Drupal provides?

Comment: Check Admin -> Structure -> Block -> User Login (None to First Sidebar)

Comment: Actually i ma new to drupal, What do you mean by (none to first sidebar)

Comment: Goto Admin -> Structure -> Blocks -> User Login & check that User Login block. If User Login is none then change it to First Sidebar.

Comment: have you check..??? @sneha

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to display it programmically
This might be helpful. put it inside  `page.tpl.php`. best of luck!

```
$elements = drupal_get_form("user_login"); 
$form = drupal_render($elements);
echo $form;
```

Comment: Its working fine, but after login page is redirecting /user/1 and giving error i.e This webpage has a redirect loop, How to solve it?

Comment: if you are using the above code in page.tpl.php files put conditions to check weather the user is login or not.